# WSO2 class mediator: Amazon aws import for sqs queue not being recognized

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, wso2, wso2-esb, mediator

So I'm trying to use the extended message support for sqs queue in wso2 integration studio. I've tried it before using eclipse (you have to build a package by specifying the required dependencies in the pom and then build it, and then create a class and run it), and it worked here. I want to now find a way to use that code in a class mediator, but i'm unsure how to go about it.
I've tried creating a class mediator in wso2, and then adding the aws dependencies to it's pom and then rebuilding, but still the import shows and error and says 'not found' when I try to add it in the java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Basically I was following the correct approach (i.e. adding the dependencies to the pom), but as I was adding it to the pom of the main mvn project, it wasn't getting reflected. It needs to be added to the pom of the class mediator and then built, before using importing it in the java class.

After that you can build the class as you would normally and copy-paste it in the ESB_HOME lib.